# It's possible access to thingsboard cloud database?

Tags: thingsboard

I want to perform queries to thingsboard cloud database.

I have a local thingsboard installed in ubuntu, to get the information of entities in thingsboard I usually perform queries directly in the thingsboard database (postgresql).

For example, I want to get email of all user:

```
select tb_user.email,customer.title from tb_user inner join customer on customer_id = customer.id;
```

But I also have a thingsboard cloud subscription, Is there a way to access the cloud database? Or how can I perform same operation in cloud platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access to cloud database.

But to get interested information you could use [Thingsboard REST API](https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui/#). Here is REST call to [get customer's users](https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui/#/user-controller/getCustomerUsersUsingGET)